# Admob Unity 5 Rewarded Video/Interstitial Wrong Orientation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, orientation, rewardedvideoad

I'm making a Android game in Unity 5 that is portrait mode only. I have now succesfully implemented the Admob Rewarded Video Ads, though they appear in landscape mode. I would like to only get them in portrait mode.
Is there any way to fix this?
I'm using the newest(I think) Admob plugins for unity.

-Lente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spoken to someone at Admob, and they said that there is currently no way to control the orientation of a Rewarded Video Ad.

Thanks,
-Lente